# Is there an overhead of multiple Task.Run that awaits without returning?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Of the 1000 tasks that have created , lets say only few (10) will complete, based on taskCompletionSource being successful in some other part of code. That means `ProcessWorkItemAsync` finished will be printed 10 times only.

**code :**

```
for (var i = 0;i<1000; i++)
{
     Task.Run(() => {
      await ProcessWorkItemAsync(); 
      Console.WriteLine("ProcessWorkItemAsync finished");
     }); 

}

async Task<TaskCompletionSource<int>> ProcessWorkItemAsync()
{
    return new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
}
```

1. Is there an CPU over head of 990 task not completing and being in a limbo ?

   - From what I have read , the thread will not be blocked, it will be returned to the thread pool, so from CPU perspective there does not appear to be any overhead.Anything else I am missing ?
2. Is there Memory overhead ?

   - because of the call stacks being stored, since dot net has to keep track where to get back to.
   - I assume these call stacks will be stored in the heap and incur a memory cost ?

Comment: To your last point, "Is there any way to check in a console application as to what Tasks are not complete and are waiting?", why not capture the Tasks you create inside your for loop, add them to an array/IEnumerable, and then inspect them later?  You can check Task.Status, Task.IsCompleted...

Comment: Of course I can do that for this simple example. For large apps I cannot do that. I was curious as whether there is infra that I can tap into .

Comment: No worries - my comment was poking into the larger context of your question, so we understand better what you want.  Now we know the context is not limited to the sample code you wrote above, but is really covering the entire app.  That context wasn't as clear (at least to me), since you started the question with "So I have a piece of code".

Comment: "the call stacks being stored" - that's an interesting idea... not related to reality so.

Comment: Note that all those task will eventually pick a threadpool thread to run... So you are pretty much guaranteed to have no free threadpool threads for some time... Which is how you get into deadlock with `.Result` without synchronization context...

Comment: Please **do not post questions twice** just because the first one got closed!

Comment: @Fildor Sorry. This was the first time my answer got closed. I was not sure whats the workflow when an answer gets closed. My bad. Should I delete this one or the other one ?

Comment: No problem. You basically have two possibilities: Edit the original question and try to improve it, considering the comments you got. Then there is a chance, it might be reopened (which this one is one vote away from). The other possibility is to author another question, that is basically a substantially improved version of the first, delete the first and post the second. You would usually chose to do the second method if the original question already gained a huge amount of negative votes.

Comment: What you see now is the edited question and I have incorporated all the feedback.

Comment: I would say close the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402161/cpu-and-memory-overhead-of-unfinished-tasks), and improve this one. It needs only one vote to be reopened. I think it's a very interesting question actually.

Comment: You can refactor your code to `for (var i = 0;i<1000; i++) { new TaskCompletionSource<int>(); }` and you have the same result as your code. 1000 created TaskCompletionSource instances with no use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of the 1000 tasks that have created , lets say only few (10) will complete, based on taskCompletionSource being successful in some other part of code. That means ProcessWorkItemAsync finished will be printed 10 times only.

The code you posted doesn't have that behavior. The posted code will print `"ProcessWorkItemAsync finished"` 1000 times and all tasks will complete almost immediately. For the rest of this answer, I'm going to address the questions and ignore the code.

> Is there an CPU over head of 990 task not completing and being in a limbo ?

No.

> From what I have read , the thread will not be blocked, it will be returned to the thread pool, so from CPU perspective there does not appear to be any overhead.Anything else I am missing ?

Tasks are not threads. The fact that you have 1000 tasks in no way implies that there are or were 1000 threads involved.

`Task.Run` does queue work to the thread pool, but when using asynchronous tasks with `Task.Run`, that thread pool thread is returned to the thread pool anytime `await` has to asynchronously wait. Whether the tasks complete or not is immaterial.

> Is there Memory overhead ?

Yes. Tasks are objects just like any other reference type. They can be rooted just like any other reference type. And if they are never cleaned up (completed), they can be [a resource leak](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/dont-forget-to-complete-your-tasks/) just like any other reference type.

> because of the call stacks being stored, since dot net has to keep track where to get back to. I assume these call stacks will be stored in the heap and incur a memory cost ?

Sort of. Call stacks are not captured or stored. The task only stores its continuations. Logically, you could think of this as a "call stack" but it only has a depth of 1. So, each task will keep alive any code that `await`s it.